# Core Data - how to set property of grandchild entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm new to CoreData and I have some problems in accessing properties of grandchild entities.
I try to build a basic shopping app and I need to design a data model.
The articles in my app may have different colors and sizes, that the user can choose.

That's the important part of my data model:

```
|Article|     |ArticleColor|      |ArticleColorSize|  
| name  |     |  color     |      |      size      |  
| brand |<-->>|            |<-->> |     stock      |  
| price |     |            |      |                |
```

(colors and sizes are represented as an int so that it would not get too complicated)

I don't know if there's a better way to design the data model, but in this case I have problems in setting the grandchild's properties. Setting the color works quite good, but I am not able to get the ArticleColor object, which I set up before, and set its ArticleColorSizes.

I hope my question got clear and someone may help me.

Edit:
I will give an example how this should work:

There is an Article (clothing) - a **shirt**
this **shirt** is available in different *colors* and *sizes* . Both are represented as an integer (resp. enum). Besides, I have to know, how many articles of a specific size and color are on *stock* .

So I thought, the easiest way to get these requirements into a data model, is the above. If I'm completely wrong, please correct me. (I have to admit that creating databases and data models is not my strength).

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

A. Are you sure that an article has many article colors and a color has many article color sizes?

B. What is an article color size, if a color is an integer?

It would be easier to understand your Q, if you add an example.

To your Q:

You go from article colors to article color size the same way you went from article to article color. There is nothing special:

```
article = …;

articleColors = article.articleColors;
articleColor = [articleColors anyObject]; // or whatever you want to get a color.

articleColorSizes = articleColors.articleColorSizes;
articleColorSize = [articleColorSizes anyObject]; // or whatever you want to get a color.
```

But I'm pretty sure that you did something wrong with your model.

Answer (score 0):

You should model the real world objects i.e. **StockItem**, **StockType**

**StockType** would include shirts, pants, etc...

**StockColor** would include available colours (red, green, etc...)

**StockSize** would include available sizes (4, 5, 6, small, medium, etc..)

These are actually just "Descriptions" that you want to standardise.

**StockItem** represents actual items in stock and would have the following attributes:

**type** - To-One relationship to StockType (inverse is To-Many relationship items on StockType)

**color** -  To-One relationship to StockColor (inverse is To-Many relationship items on StockColor)

**size** -  To-One relationship to StockSize (inverse is To-Many relationship items on StockSize)

**barCode** - if each item has a distinct barcode or serial number and you want to track at an item level

**quantityAvailable** - available for sale (if items don't have unique barcodes and you only need to track quantity in stock)

**quantityReserved** - items in stock but sold and not shipped yet

There are books on domain or business modelling that explain this in more detail.